# On sandbox refresh/new sandbox is there a way of preventing it from copying over priceBookEntries?

Tags: sandbox-refresh

Or at least filtering which pricebooks are brought or OR which pricebook entries are brought over.

Because it's blowing up the data limits and causing all sorts of hell in our sandboxes. We'd rather load the data we need  ourselves for our requirements rather than being thrown junk data we don't need.

It becomes a real struggle when we have to delete all of those entries and all of the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "refresh" isn't just modifying metadata. In the backend, an entirely new org is created, populated with fresh metadata, and once activated, becomes the new active org. The old org is entirely deleted after a brief delay. You can create a [Sandbox Template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_templates.htm&type=5) to select data to bring over, but this only applies to Full and Partial Sandboxes. Note that Price Books and Price Book Entries do not contribute to storage usage, as stated in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_monitorresources.htm&type=5).

> Active or archived products, price books, price book entries, and assets don’t count against storage.

Comment: Is there still anyway of preventing the pricebook entries from migrating over. We have a complex relationship structure with product2 which isn't brought over and has to be brought in manually. We use templates but the existing data in sandboxes causes some issues with migrating data, which causes a whole day + some just deleting pricebook entries and products.

Comment: @ensir Write a [Batchable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) script, and a [SandboxPostCopy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm) script, having the latter call the former when called, then you can specify this script whilst creating/refreshing the Sandbox to do any cleanup you want to do.